# Docusign for Salesforce Javascript or API ? Need to pass a document ID

Tags: javascript, salesforce, docusignapi

I am trying to create a javascript button to docusign as outlined in the standard admin manual that references a specific salesforce document via document ID to be merged.  I cannot find any documented method of providing a document ID via the javascript.  Do I need to access docusign via an API call?

Comment: The document I want to add will be stored in chatter files.  The only option I see is the LA option to include ALL attachments... I just want to a single one and I need to be able to call it by Salesforce ID

Comment: Questions on SO should be self-contained. Could you summarize what is outlined in the referenced admin manual?

Comment: Great point Marcus that's exactly how this site should be used - please provide more info on what you're trying to achieve and what documentation you are referring to...

Comment: The documentation just provides descriptions of URL Parameters that Docusign Accepts. No issue creating button.

Essentially I am trying to create a custom link to the docusign for salesforce service. I am trying to find out if I can pass a specific documentID as a parameter to Docusign. It is not documented in the  manual. It's possible over API, but I wanted to see if anyone might have done it with the link. Tried DS support, they suggested posting here, that someone familiar with the service could help. Sorry if this is the wrong place for this.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer somewhere else and figured I would share here if someone is searching. Supplying a specific document ID is not supported through the normal Docusign Link parameters.  I will be creating an API call to fulfill my requirement.